# Deploy Registry Change

Tags: c#, deployment, powershell, registry

What is the best way to deploy a HKCU registry change for **anyone** who logs onto the machine. Someone mentioned to me Active Setup...but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via GPO user logon script.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to run a powershell script when the user logs on that edits the registry. I would do this from windows scheduler.

Comment: That may work for one machine...but assume a large company that has 1000+ users.

Comment: I believe it is possible using the windows task scheduler. Just have it run a script when the user logs on.